Hyperref help needed
I'm trying to set my hyperref environment to replicate this paper's style: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1126-6708/2000/04/018/pdf
But I can't seem to get it and all hyperref manuals I find are quite technical and non-illustrative, can you guys help me?

Welcome to TeX StackExchange! Questions are best if they're self-contained. Could you include an explanation and screenshot of what you hope to achieve? It'd also be great if you could edit your question to show your attempt so far

Is this something like what you’re looking for? In the example you linked, it looks like every type of link has a dashed blue border around it except for footnotes. I tried my best to recreate that minus the footnotes, which I disabled with hyperfootnotes=false.
In the code below, pdfborderstyle, the two numbers in [3.5 2.5] controls the length of each dash, and the gap size between dashes, respectively, as measured in units of points. The number after W is the width (thickness) of the dashes in units of points.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  allcolors=blue,
  allbordercolors={0 0 1},
  pdfborderstyle={/S/D/D[3.5 2.5]/W 1}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Hi there!}
\subsection{Nice to meet you}
\label{sec:greeting}

This is the first sentence in Section \ref{sec:greeting}. 

According to some great mathematicians \cite{ExampleCitation}, it can be proved that
\begin{equation}
1 + 1 \neq -1. \tag{Amazing Lemma} \label{eq:astonishing_theorem}
\end{equation}

The \ref{eq:astonishing_theorem} has revolutionized mathematics.\footnote{Want to know a secret? This theorem is actually pretty trivial.}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
  \bibitem{ExampleCitation} 
  Audrey Author and Carrie Coauthor. 1999. \emph{Example citation}. Retrieved from \url{https://www.example.com}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

